# WSO2 Api Manager Sample Code for User Own Java API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The WSO2 Api manager documentation only shows how to setup youtube statistics as api, but there is no example found about how to use developers own web service to be exported as API using publisher
My Question is
How can I use user defined java web service calls to be managed thru WSO2 API Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best example will be trying out PizzaShack sample inside API Manager. There are two java based web applications pizza-shack-web and pizza-shack-api in the sample which will be deployed as web services in WSO2 Application Server.
Then 3 APIs will be created in WSO2 API Manager as Delivery API, Order API and Menu API which are consuming the pizza-shack-api service. 
Please follow the README inside the sample.

Steps to setup sample

1. Go to WSO2_AM_HOME/samples/PizzaShack and execute mvn clean install from there. It will download the required artifacts to run the sample including the README.

Note: If you are using WSO2 API Manager 1.5.0, please change the WSO2_AM_HOME/samples/PizzaShack/pre-processor/pom.xml with below change and then follow instruction 1 above.

Replace https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/**4.2.0**/products/apimgt/1.5.0/modules/samples/PizzaShack/PizzaShack.zip

with

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/**turing**/products/apimgt/1.5.0/modules/samples/PizzaShack/PizzaShack.zip

Comment: Can I get configuration of the three apis mentioned in your advice, Delivery API, Order API and Menu API

Comment: Confgiuration details are there inside the README file of https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.5.0/modules/samples/PizzaShack/PizzaShack.zip It contains the information for required fields when creating the APIs from the Publisher.